# Why my WIFI ADB ULTIMATE Plugin doesn't work on Android Studio 4.1?

Tags: android, adb, wifi

In this post, I want to share my experience to solve the problem like in the title of this post.

So, the original plugin didn't work for me after the android studio 4.1 update so I found plugin dependencies to work with it.
direct download (Install it with "Install plugin from disk" option): https://github.com/YahiaAngelo/WIFIADB/raw/master/WIFIADBIntelliJPlugin/out/WIFI_ADB_ULTIMATE-1.1.1.zip
repo: https://github.com/YahiaAngelo/WIFIADB

Official Post: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/jb5f1p/wifi_adb_ultimate_plugin_for_android_studio_41/